# drawerlayout + CoordinatorLayout in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-coordinatorlayout, drawerlayout

Please help me.
Failed to execute the program with the following code in Xamarin.android:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffeceff1"
    >
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbarmain"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"

            >
                    <LinearLayout
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/..."
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/..."
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:maxWidth="70dp"
                            android:maxHeight="60dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:id="@+id/..."
                            android:background="@drawable/..."
                            android:layout_height="100dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|clip_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    >
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/..."
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu1"
                        android:background="@drawable/click"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="..."
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtcalender"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/calender"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:id="@+id/recyclermain"
                    >
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/design_fab_size_normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarmain"

            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" 
            android:clickable="true"


        >
        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Error:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Views.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating
>   class TextView ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #1: Error inflating class TextView --->
>   Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute
>   at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727729/fatal-exception-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-failed-to-resolve-attr    and    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004886/android-app-crash-after-settext-on-a-textview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727729/fatal-exception-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-failed-to-resolve-attr)